# Add period into matched pattern in regex in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to replace

> underline{someword}

with

> underline{someword.}

in Vim.

I've tried

```
:%s/underline{\w*}/underline{$1\.}/g
```

but it changes the matched patterns to

> underline{$1.}

Why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the capture group

```
:%s/underline{\(\w*\)}/underline{\1\.}/g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use grouping:

```
:%s/\(underline{\w*\)}/\1\.}/g
```

Here `\(...\)` is used for grouping the match.

Answer (score 3):

Use the ever-underappreciated `\zs` and `\ze`:

```
:%s/\munderline{\w*\zs\ze}/./g
```